# MongoDB/Mongoose: Using $sum to calculate quantity when names are matching

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some data within a mongodb collection which looks like this:

```
[
        {
                "name" : "Apple",
                "quantity" : "4",
          
        },
        {
                "name" : "Apple",
                "quantity" : "6",
                
        },
        {
                "name" : "Orange",
                "quantity" : "2",
        },
        {
                "name" : "Orange",
                "quantity" : "3",
                
        },
]
```

I am trying to figure out a mongodb query and then its mongoose counterpart where I could utilize $sum to get all unique names with their respective sum. So the correct output after the query should look like this:

```
[
 {
   name: "Apple",
   totalQuantity: "10"
 },
 {
   name: "Orange",
   totalQuantity: "5"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) will group documents by specified fields,

- `$group` by `name`
- `$toInt` convert string `quantity` to integer and `$sum` into `totalQuantity`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      totalQuantity: {
        $sum: { $toInt: "$quantity" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
      totalQuantity: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vMEbZ4i2igF)